# Testing programically for file hole support

Tags: filesystems

Is there a system call for testing whether the filesystem supports holes in files given a pathname?

I thought of having a holes_supported() function in my API and I would like to know if such a test can actually be implemented.

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718864/how-to-test-if-sparse-file-is-supported

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a dummy sparse file on the filesystem in question with [`truncate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate), check the "apparent" and the "real" size.

[Details here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sparse_file)

A file-system needs to support the `SEEK_HOLE` `lseek` flag.

@DepressedDaniel points out, that `truncate` uses the [`ftruncate` system call](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate).